# How can I clear a card in a GmailApp?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I have a Card object in a GmailApp with some widgets.
I want to clear the card after pressing a button.

How can I do that?

Comment: This is a basic method handled by the `Navigation` class - just pop the card and view a simpler one underneath it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by updating an empty card in the current navigation in the callback of the button action. Follow the below piece of code:

```js
function getCard() {
var cb = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  
   cb.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Card Header"));

   var section = CardService.newCardSection();

var submitForm = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('clearCard');
var submitButton = CardService.newTextButton().setText('Clear Card').setOnClickAction(submitForm);
section.addWidget(submitButton);

cb.addSection(section);

return cb.build();
}

function clearCard(e) {
 var navigation = CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(emptyCard());
   return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder().setNavigation(navigation).build();
}

function getEmptyWidget() {
  return CardService.newKeyValue().setContent("");
}

function getEmptySection() {
  return CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(getEmptyWidget());
}

function emptyCard() {
 var cb = CardService.newCardBuilder();
 cb.setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle("Card Header"));

 cb.addSection(getEmptySection());

 return cb.build();
}
```